# Python 3.6.4 Arcade Module Window Errors? {pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'invalid enumerant'}

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, window, arcade

**UPDATE:**

I checked the graphics cards installed on the computers.

The one where it "works" has Nvidia Graphics and the other has Intel HD R graphics under display adapter in Device Manager. I'm assuming the Intel HD R graphics driver is not sufficient (does not contain the OpenGL required?).

*What do I need to get on the Intel HD R graphics computer in order for the arcade module to work?*

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

*Experiencing a very weird issue where python code I've written works on one computer but not on another one and I'm not sure why...*

**I have Python 3.6.4 installed on both computers.**
Any version which is 3.6 + should be able to run the Arcade module.

**This is my code, super simple stuff:**

```
# import needed modules
import random
import arcade

arcade.open_window(800, 600,'most awesome nothing', False)
arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.BLUE)
arcade.start_render()

python = arcade.Sprite(r"C:\Users\The Cube\Desktop\STUDENT FILES\Python Game Projects - Teens\diamond.png")

python.center_x = 200
python.center_y = 200
python.draw()

arcade.finish_render()
arcade.run()
```

Works fine on one computer, but on the other, I get this error:

**Code Format:**

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
 RESTART: C:\Users\The Cube\Desktop\STUDENT FILES\Python Game Projects - Teens\phoenix is a cool cat.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\The Cube\Desktop\STUDENT FILES\Python Game Projects - Teens\phoenix is a cool cat.py", line 5, in <module>
    arcade.open_window(800, 600,'most awesome nothing', False)
  File "C:\Users\The Cube\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\application.py", line 384, in open_window
    _window = Window(width, height, window_title, resizable, update_rate=None)
  File "C:\Users\The Cube\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\application.py", line 56, in __init__
    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB)
  File "C:\Users\The Cube\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\lib.py", line 105, in errcheck
    raise GLException(msg)
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'invalid enumerant'
>>>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Question: Why does it work on one computer and not the other?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code enables OpenGL multisampling. It is required for anti-aliasing. It appears that isn't supported with the graphics card/driver combination.

You can create an arcade.Window instance with `antialiasing=False`, but the `open_window` command you are using unfortunately does not support that in 2.0.1.

As issue has been opened to downgrade gracefully if multisampling isn't supported:

https://github.com/pvcraven/arcade/issues/339